# select and calculate numdays from two tables in oracle

Tags: oracle

I m doing a leave calculation. I have Leave requested table and Employee Table.

Their relationship is Employee can request many Leaves. i.e

Leave request table has Employee_Serail_ID as one to many. I have done the following query to select all leave request and calculkate the number of days.

```
    SELECT (LR.DATE_TO - LR.DATE_FROM) as NumDays ,
    LR.EMPLOYEE_SERIAL_ID, LR.ID as LEAVE_REQUEST_ID         
    FROM TBL_LEAVE_REQUEST LR ;

NUMDAYS EMPLOYEE_SERIAL_ID LEAVE_REQUEST_ID
     3 EMP_286  LEAVE_35                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
     2 EMP_243  LEAVE_36                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
     2 EMP_284  LEAVE_37                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
     3 EMP_243  LEAVE_38                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    32 EMP_243  LEAVE_39                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
     0 EMP_303  LEAVE_40                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
     1 EMP_241  LEAVE_41
```

But , i figured out that all employee who have not requested leave will not be selected using this query.

I want to modify this query that - if the employee has rquested a leave it will show the numdays , and if it has not this query should return Numdays 0 for all employees.

Numdays

Comment: What database are you actually using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to `left join` your leave request table to your actual employee table. This will give you an employee record, even if they don't have a leave request.

Since you haven't posted your schema, and you haven't specified what database you're actually using, I can't write much of the query for you. Your logic will look something like this:

```
SELECT 
    T.EMPLOYEE_ID
    , ISNULL((LR.DATE_TO - LR.DATE_FROM), 0) as NumDays
    , LR.EMPLOYEE_SERIAL_ID
    , LR.ID as LEAVE_REQUEST_ID         
FROM 
    TBL_EMPLOYEE T
    LEFT JOIN TBL_LEAVE_REQUEST LR
        on T.EMPLOYEE_ID = LR.EMPLOYEE_ID
;
```

The `ISNULL` function is used by MSSQL Server. Other databases require different functions.

- If you're using Oracle, replace `ISNULL(` with `NVL(`.
- If you're using PostgreSQL or MySQL, you'll want the command `COALESCE(`.

---

A note in `ISNULL()` and `NVL()` vs `COALESCE()`. As @Ronnis pointed out, any ANSI compliant database should support the `COALESCE()` function.

Looking into the documentation a little further, you may get better query performance using `COALESCE()` than  `NVL()` or `ISNULL()`. The former will short circuit its evaluation, whereas the other two will not.

Comment: I think the better solution is to use the ANSI-compliant alternative COALESCE regardless of what database you use.

Comment: @Ronnis: That's a decent point. I've added a note about that to the answer.